# Set the initial value for select by selectize.js?

Tags: javascript, c#, .net, model-view-controller, selectize.js

I want to display the initial value when initialized but it doesn't seem to work. I tried to research and found a way but couldn't.

HTML

```
 <select class="select-links" multiple id="selectID">
    <option value="KR" selected="selected">Koren</option>
 </select>
```

JS

```
var select = $('.select-links').selectize({
    valueField: 'url',
    searchField: 'title',
    plugins: ['remove_button'],
    options: [],
    render: {
        option: function (data, escape) {
            return '<div class="option">' +
                '<span class="title">' + escape(data.title) + '</span>' +
                '<span class="url">' + escape(data.url) + '</span>' +
                '</div>';
        },
        item: function (data, escape) {
            return '<div class="item">' + escape(data.title) + '</div>';
        }
    },
    load: function (query, callback) {
        if (!query.length) return callback();
        $.ajax({
            url: "/account.json",
            type: 'POST',
            error: function () {
                callback();
            },
            success: function (data) {
                var Array_User = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < data.array.length; i++) {
                    var obj = data.array[i];
                    Array_User.push({ id: obj.ID, name: obj.Full_Name, email: obj.Email });
                }
                callback(Array_User)
            }
        });
    }

});
```